# Listen for updates - backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm doing an app using webs-ockets and backbone. Where should I listen to data updates? In views? or in models?

Also I would like to know appropriate place to listen user events.

Answer (score 2):

Backbone events are not (websocket) API events.

You're probably looking for the `websocket.onmessage` event.
When you got this event, say on a (Backbone) `Model`, you could `trigger()` an event on the `Model` and let all listeners (probably `View` objects of Backbone) handle it.

Hope that helps in a way.